# Powershell regex to replace pattern

Tags: regex

My script should look for a comma separated 3 digit version number (eg. 1.2.3)
and replace it with the new version number. The same file has another string which doesnt meet this regex still the script changes it.

Samplefile.txt

```
  "search-components@1.1.1"
  "e2bf8da9-275a-484d-95a6-7e6b8c0ce0ca"
```

Replace command portion from the Script:

```
  -replace "\d.\d.\d","2.2.2"
```

I expect it to give output like this,

```
  "search-components@2.2.2"
  "e2bf8da9-275a-484d-95a6-7e6b8c0ce0ca" # This string not changed
```

But it changes the second string too as follows which I didn't intent to

```
   e2bf8da2.2.2a-484d-92.2.2e2.2.2ce0ca
```

Am I wriitng the regex all wrong. Can someone help please?

Comment: The _"dot"_ (aka _period_ `.`) in a regex is the match-anything meta-character, so `\d.\d.\d` matches "a digit followed by any character followed by a digit followed by any character followed by a digit". See Kasra's answer for making the dot a plain dot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the dots in your regex :

```
"\d\.\d\.\d"
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iS2fL7/2)